# Type Aliases in MySQL / MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Does MySQL / MariaDB have a mechanism for type aliases (like C's `typedefs`).

For example I would like to use it like this (image the SQL syntax would be the same as it is in C):

```sql
typdef bigint(20) UNSIGNED KEY_TYPE

CREATE TABLE `Foo` (
    `id`     KEY_TYPE  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`steamlogin_id`)
);
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html doesn't mention it, so I doubt it. Have you done any research into this yourself?

Comment: @Lehks . . . In SQL, these are called "user defined types" and MySQL does not support them.